# Put loading stage before the result is ready in jsf ajax event

Tags: ajax, jsf

I want to put loading sign before the result would be delivered to me.

for example I can change press different colors with this:

```
<!-- ColorFilter -->
                    <span class="select-one-container">
                        <p:selectOneButton id="colorFilter" value="#{productView.color}">
                            <p:ajax update="mainForm" listener="#{productView.applyFilters}" oncomplete="PF('colorTable').filter();"/>
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel=" #{colorText.filter_new} " itemValue="red" itemDescription="#{pRevText.filter_new_description}"/>
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel=" #{pRevText.filter_marked}" itemValue="blue" itemDescription="#{pRevText.filter_marked_description}"/>                            
                        </p:selectOneButton>
                    </span>
```

and before "applyFilters" is done, it should just show loading sign, i do not want to see the old results there

or just not show anything before the results come back

Is there an option before "oncomplete" for ajax events?

Comment: Tried using https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/blockUI.xhtml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an option before "oncomplete" for ajax events?

`onstart`

Another option is ajax status:
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/status.xhtml

and blockUI as suggested by @AshishMathew.